# php, existing array entry with Null value

Tags: php

In a php script I have the following lines:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select zHD, EMail ...");
...     
$res = $stmt->execute();
...
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($row);   
if ($row["Email"] === NULL) {
```

In 1 case I get the folling var_dump values:

```
array(2) {
  ["zHD"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["EMail"]=>
  NULL
}
```

In this situation I also get a PHP-Notice for the next line after the var_dump:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Email in ...
```

Is this really true, that you get an "undefined index" warning for an EXISTING entry
of an array, which has a NULL value?

Or am I missing something else?

What is the best way, the best command to include this case after the var_dump command?

Thank you alot in advance

Update: Thank you for your help. This is something, where pair programming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming)
would be good!

Comment: Your column is named 'EMail' not 'Email' - look at the capitalisation.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I totally overlooked it!

Comment: it happens often .. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is because you are accessing wrong index key of array.

```
if ($row["Email"] === NULL) {
```

that should be

```
if ($row["EMail"] === NULL) {
```

Answer (score 2):

replace `$row["Email"]` with `$row["EMail"]`  ... You are using wrong index